# send button on contact form doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: forms, mobile

What could be the reason that a contact form works perfectly fine on a desktop, but fails on a mobile device?

I have a contact form as part of a html template, that i believe uses ajax and php mailer to send email notifications to the contact form owner.

When testing this card on the desktop, it works absolutely fine, but fails when on a mobile device. There are no error messages displayed, but the URL is full of variables passed to the form. When the button is pressed the user is redirected to the main div, but the contact form does not get processed.

Any ideas?